# Vuex Chartist display data

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2, vuex

I have a problem with display data

**this is my App.vue file:**

```
mounted() { 
    this.$store.dispatch('getLocation'),
    this.$store.dispatch('renderChart', this.$el);
},
```

**my store.js looks like that**

```
mutations: {
    setLocation (state, { locations, forecast }) {
      state.location = locations;
      state.forecast = forecast.consolidated_weather.map(item => {
        return Number(Math.round(item['the_temp']))
      });
      state.data.series.push(state.forecast);
      console.log(state.data.series)
    },
    setChart(state, {context, payload}) {
      state.chartist = new Chartist['Line'](context, state.data, state.options, state.responsiveOptions)
      console.log(context,)
    }
  },
  actions: {
    renderChart({commit}, context, payload) {
      commit('setChart', {context, payload})
    },
    getLocation ({ commit }) {
      const url = `${API_URL}location/560743/`    
      axios.get(url)
        .then(response => commit('setLocation', { 
          locations: response.data,
          forecast: response.data
         }))
        .catch(e => console.log(e))
    }
  }
```

The data doesn't load when i refresh browser. But when i move `this.$store.dispatch('renderChart', this.$el);` to created() then the data is displayed but after refresh doesnt load again. It is probably something with lifecycle hooks but im not really sure. Any ideas?

Comment: I think your `renderChart` action is strange. Vuex action can take at most 1 parameter but you have two (`context` and `payload`)

Comment: I guess `context` must be inside `{ }`